# Searching Arrays with Strings from other Arrays C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I have this thing for checking if the client entered some help command in the arguments while triggering the console application I've built in C#. Below is my current code to complete this task:

```
string[] help = { "-h", "--help", "/?", "help", "-help", "*help*" };
if (args.Contains(help[*])
{
    Usage(); // prints out application usage
    Environment.Exit(1); // exits console application only
}
```

I originally used the following, which worked, but I wanted to clean the code up a little bit:

```
if (args.Contains("-h") || args.Contains("--help") || args.Contains("/?") ...)
{
    Usage();
    Environment.Exit(1);
}
```

How would I perform the task I'm trying to perform in the cleanest coded way possible?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: totally not an answer. I suggest checking out [NDesk.Options](http://www.ndesk.org/Options)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about `args.Any(arg => help.Contains(arg))`?